# значение типа "const char *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi

Пробовал включить многобайтовую кодировку, все равно эта ошибка. Что нужно сделать, чтобы каждый раз не приходилось писать (TEXT)?

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("WinMainClass");
```

Comment: Букву `W` видите? это указатель на `wchar_t`, а не на `char`. "Длинные" строки обычно получают при помощи префикса `L`, типа `L"Hello"`.

Comment: @Harry Собирал через g++, все работало

Comment: Ну тогда могу только посоветовать "собирать через g++", и не задавать вопросы, ответы на которые у вас уже есть...

Comment: @Harry так мне надо собрать через студию

Comment: @Harry Подскажите,пожалуйста,что на что поменять, чтобы собралось в студии

Comment: В студии нужно каждый раз писать `TEXT(...)` или `_T(...)`. В этом случае можно написать приложение, которое при включении/выключении поддержки юникода будет нормально компилироваться и работать.

Comment: @KoVadim То есть, это неотъемлемая часть?

Comment: можно наверно так сказать. Вот только это "часть студийного компилятора/библиотеки", а не собственно самого с++.

Comment: Никакие `TEXT` или `_T` не нужны. Необходимо везде использовать широкие символы. `WNDCLASSEXW wc; wc.lpszClassName = L"WinMainClass";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макрос `TEXT` сделан для облегчения задачи программиста.

В зависимости от того, является ли Ваш прожект unicode или ascii, он
даёт разные результаты:
а) если прожект unicode - то "разворачивается" в wchar_t*
б) если прожект ascii - то в char*

`WNDCLASSEX` так же в зависимости от кодировки прожекта становится либо
а) `WNDCLASSEXW` с полем **LPCWSTR** `lpszClassName`
либо
б) `WNDCLASSEXA` с полем **LPCSTR** `lpszClassName`

Облегчение задачи состоит в том, что, используя `TEXT`, Вам не придётся переписывать исходный код при смене режимов unicode|ascii.
При использовании функций api вообще никаких проблем не должно возникать.
Для своих же переменных следует использовать TCHAR и "производные" от него типы (LPTSTR например). А так же варианты функций для обработки строк, которые используют TCHAR

Answer (score 2):

Это разные типы данных! `LPCWSTR` это `wchar_t*`(другой вид строк), а `char*` это однобайтовая строка. Вы можете использовать

```
TEXT("вашаСтрока")
```

Или

```
L"ваша строка"
```